# Remove native styles for select input on Mac, keep down arrow

Tags: html, css, html-select

I'm styling some select inputs on a page, and it works fine on Windows Chrome. However, on Mac Chrome, the "native" implementation refuses to go away unless I apply `-webkit-appearance: none;` The problem with this, of course, is that I lose the down arrow that indicates it's a `select` element, which I would otherwise be able to add back in if inputs were allowed pseudo-elements (they're not).

Specifically, I'm trying to override the `border-radius` property, but no amount of `border-radius: 0!important` will override it.

Comment: You can change the look by setting background to a solid color or setting border to none or border-style to solid. Either one removes the glossy look. But the result is not very aesthetically pleasing. Also the border-radius won't go. I've seen a cross-browser approach where someone wrapped the select with a div, and put a background-image behind, with the select's background set to transparent. It's a workaroud at least...

Answer (score -1):

Create or download a small down arrow and then give the following property to you select:

```
select{-webkit-appearance: none;
background:url(images/downarrow.png) no-repeat;
background-position: 98% 4px; }
```